# How to handle AsyncCallback for receiving if there is no response after Socket.BeginReceive

Tags: c#, sockets

An `AsyncCallback` after `Socket.BeginReceive` is not called while the server is being initialized during startup.

```
mSocket.BeginReceive(mBuffer, 0, mBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(onReceive), mSocket);
```

```
private void onReceive(IAsyncResult result)
{
    if (mSocket == null) return;
    Monitor.Enter(mLockObj);
    mSocket.EndReceive(result);
    //...
```

Do I need to create some timeout logic or is there an exception case I can catch and handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `AsyncCallback` is, well, `async`, it will be waiting to receive indefinitely until it returns, so there will be no "timeout" exception.

Some options were explored in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466332/beginreceive-beginread-timeouts), but, to answer your question, you'll essentially have to implement your own timeout method.